# JS equivalent to Jquery attribute not equal to

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve this in pure JS with no jQuery:

```
$('td[colspan!=20] a')
```

Is there a way to do that only with document.**querySelectorAll** ? (without filtering results) ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class selector to specify which all elements should be excluded

```
document.querySelectorAll( "td:not([colspan='20']" );
```

**Demo**

```js
var result = document.querySelectorAll( "td:not([colspan='20']" );
console.log(result.length)
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="1"></td>
     <td colspan="20"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use any valid CSS selector in [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) methods.